# Tool to convert HTML entities & numeric code representations of Unicode characters to UTF-8 (Windows CLI)

Tags: html, command-line, file-converter, unicode, encoding

Please recommend a gratis command-line (CLI) tool for Windows that will convert all HTML entities as well as common Unicode character numeric code representations within ANSI/UTF-7 encoded text files to their UTF-8 equivalents.

It can either directly output the contents to a UTF-8 encoded text file, or simply send the output to `stdout`, and I'll programmatically redirect the output to a file.

The data is all pages that have been scraped from the internet using HTTPS `GET` & `POST` requests.

I'm currently using a `sed` script I wrote to do this, and it has gotten very lengthy (and thus somewhat slow).

For example, `&amp;`, `&#38;`, and `&#38;` all need to be converted to `&`.

Thus, when a file with this content is used for input:

```
This &amp; that.
Bells &#38; whistles.
Dogs &#038; cats.
```

The output needs to be:

```
This & that.
Bells & whistles.
Dogs & cats.
```

Ideally, I would like the tool to also handle converting:

```
&#231;
&#234;
&#241;
```

to:

```
ç
ê
ñ
```

Open source code is preferred, but not required.  Portable (no installer and no registry modifications) is required.  Cross-platform compatibility with Linux is a big plus, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

There is a unix command called `recode` that can do this.  You can find a Windows port as part of [UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and there is a [Chocolatey package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/unxUtils) which would install and add it to your PATH.

Example output:

```
C:\>type temp.txt
This &amp; that.
Bells &#38; whistles.
Dogs &#038; cats.
&#231;
&#234;
&#241;
C:\>recode html..utf8 temp.txt

C:\>type temp.txt 
This & that.
Bells & whistles.
Dogs & cats.
ç
ê
ñ
```